# Level vs. conductor of a supercuspidal representation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, supercuspidal-representations

What is the relation between level and conductor of a supercuspidal representation of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ for some prime $p$?

Proposition 3.4 in [Loeffler and Weinstein - On the computation of local components of a newform](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2796) refers to [Breuil and Mézard - Multiplicités modulaires et représentations de $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z_p)$
et de $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}_p/\mathbb Q_p)$ en $\ell = p$. Appendice par Guy Henniart. Sur l'unicité des types pour $\operatorname{GL}_2$](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~breuil/PUBLICATIONS/multiplicite.pdf), which I am unable to understand because of the language.

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but the PDFs to which you linked won't load.  I changed the arXiv PDF link to an abstract link, as is the usual convention, but I had to guess at the Breuil paper, which I think is [Breuil and Mézard - Multiplicités modulaires et représentations de $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ et de $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q_p}/\mathbb Q_p)$ en $\ell = p$](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1085598143) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1944572)).

Comment: I explained how to get this from standard references in Section 2.2 of [my basis problem paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.04234).  You get that the level is one less than one half of the conductor.

Comment: @Kimball, it may be necessary to be cautious here:  I think that there are notions of normalised and of un-normalised level.  According to [Bushnell, Henniart, and Kutzko - Local Rankin–Selberg convolutions for $\operatorname{GL}_n$](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1998-11-03/S0894-0347-98-00270-7), the level is an integer $m$, and $\frac m e = \frac1 2(f - 1)$, where $e = 1$ if $\pi$ is unramified and $e = 2$ if $\pi$ is unramified.  Probably you are using a normalised notion, where the level is the rational number $m/e$?

Comment: @LSpice Maybe I should have clarified, but the question was about supercuspidal $\pi$, and I am only stating what you get when $\pi$ is discrete series, so $e=2$ in your notation, using the normalization of level as in Bushnell-Henniart's book.  I haven't looked at Bushnell-Henniart-Kutzko, at least not in detail, but I thought the references I use (which are just for GL(2)) might be a candidate for "a more elementary reference" that you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: @Kimball, [definitely](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360614/level-vs-conductor-of-a-supercuspidal-representation#comment908786_360614), and I think you should post [it](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360614/level-vs-conductor-of-a-supercuspidal-representation#comment908588_360614) as an answer.  However, I'm pretty sure that, even for supercuspidals, $e$ can be $1$ or $2$ (or else I'm totally misunderstanding their notation, which is entirely possible).

Comment: @LSpice Well, I didn't want to flesh things out anymore since there's and your answer was already accepted.  Oh, I didn't realize by unramified you meant "unramified supercuspidal" in the sense that Bushnell, Henniart, etc use (which I personally dislike for what I hope are obvious reasons).  Yes, then there might be some normalization of the level one needs to go between your answer and my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a more elementary reference, but, according to [Bushnell, Henniart, and Kutzko - Local Rankin–Selberg convolutions for $\operatorname{GL}_n$](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1998-11-03/S0894-0347-98-00270-7), (6.1.2), if $m$ is the level of $\pi$, then the conductor of $\pi$ depends on a choice of additive character $\psi$, which will be trivial on $\mathfrak p^{c(\psi)}$ but not on $\mathfrak p^{c(\psi) - 1}$ for some integer $c(\psi)$, and is given by
$$
f(\pi) = 2(1 + c(\psi) + m/e),
$$
where $e$ is $1$ if $\pi$ is unramified and $2$ if $\pi$ is ramified.

EDIT:  I'll leave this answer since it's been accepted, but @Kimball's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360614/level-vs-conductor-of-a-supercuspidal-representation#comment908588_360614) provides a better, as more elementary, reference in Section 2.2 of his paper [Kimball - The basis problem revisited](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.04234).

Comment: If we choose $c(\psi)$ to be $0$, can we say something about $\pi$?

Comment: @Kiddo, there is no "*the* conductor of $\pi$"; it depends on a choice of $\psi$, so that (as the reference indicates) one should really write $f(\pi, \psi)$.  We may certainly choose $\psi$ as you say, and it simplifies the formula, but of course doesn't affect $\pi$ at all.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Theorem 6.5,(ii) says $f(\sigma_1' \otimes \sigma_2)= n_1n_2(1+m/e)$. What is this $m$? It is not mentioned in the theorem. Is it the level of $\sigma_1' \otimes \sigma_2$?

Comment: @Kiddo, as the statement of the theorem says, [it](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360614/level-vs-conductor-of-a-supercuspidal-representation/360617#comment908570_360617) is notation (6.2.1):  $m/e = \max (m_1/e_1, m_2/e_2)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot...